# Why placing framework folder outside public root is safer?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, symfony, yii

Why it is always recommended to place framework files outside of the public root ?

Given that sometimes a framework doesn't have `.ini` or `.inc` files that can be opened by a browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there is definitely nothing to be *gained* from placing framework sources inside the web root. Since the choice of where to place the file is therefore free, it's only logical to go with the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege): you don't need web access to these files, so you won't get it.

A more concrete reason is that framework sources can easily disclose the brand and version of a framework being used on a website (although this information can also usually be gained by examining the generated content); this in turn can make it easier for malicious users to exploit known or newly discovered vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 5):

This is safer because if there is any misconfiguration in web server, then it is possible that script files (be it .php, .asp or whatever) can be spit out in plain text and potential attacker sees all your source code and defined passwords. So the best practice is to put only index.php file in webroot which in turn includes bootstrap script from outside webroot.

I remember one real world example - in Latvia, where I live, we have large social network "draugiem.lv" (in our country more popular than Facebook) and few years ago all their PHP source code leaked by misconfigured server, as I described earlier.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the standard reasons cited by the other answers - server mis-configuration, principle of least privilege, etc - it is worth noting that many frameworks, including Zend Framework, can use config files that are in formats other than PHP, e.g., `.ini`, `.yml`, etc.

If these were in the public-accessible web root, then - depending upon server config - they would be served directly to anyone who requests them. Since these config files typically contain sensitive information like db passwords, API-keys, etc, it is certainly desirable to make them as inaccessible as possible.

As an example, consider `application/configs/application.ini`. If the doc root were at the project-folder level, then a request for:

`http://example.com/application/configs/application.ini`

would deliver the keys to the castle.

Comment: App-specific configuration files *inside the framework sources directory*? I can't rule that out of course but it's horrible beyond words. What framework does that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand precisely what you mean by "framework sources directory". But the point is that typically a project directory has several sub-directories, one of which is intended to be public (mapped to a url at the web-server level) and a bunch of others for libraries, controllers, views, and - most pointedly - config. If the entire project dir were public, then the config files would be directly web-acessible. Anyway, we both surely agree that keeping the bulk of the app outside the doc root is a worthwhile recommended practice. Thanks and cheers! ;-)